# Why is the V/Q Ratio 0.8 not 1?

Tags: physiology, respiration

According to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ventilation/perfusion_ratio the ideal V/Q Ratio would be 1.0 because 1 L of blood can hold about 200 mL of oxygen and 1L of humidified air has about 200 mL of oxygen.

However, the actual ventilation/perfusion ratio for the entire lung is described as 0.8. I understand there are regional variations due to gravity, but on the whole, shouldn't the **average** V/Q ratio be 1?

One thought I had was that because it takes time for O2 to diffuse across the membranes and bind to Hemoglobin, that could explain this loss in efficiency.